# iOS app install error "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to install Ad-hoc app on iPhone, but the installation couldn't get complete and get the message. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here. Got any fix?

Comment: Any updates? Did you fix it?